# Hold state after adding to DOM

Tags: jquery

I am loading, through an API call, images and image title to the DOM e.g.

```
var html = '';
var i=0, length=data.length, image;
for(; i<length; i++) {
html += '<li>';
html += '<div class="holder">';
html += '<div class="image"><img src="/path/to/image.jpg"></div>';
html += '<div class="imgTitle">Image title</div>';
html += '</div>';
html += '</li>';
}

$('#images').append(html);
```

I am limiting this to say 10, then onClick of a button load the next 10. Standard stuff.

Now, on the click of a different button I want to hide the text and just show images, or click back on again, so something like

```
$('#txtHide').click(function() {
    $('.imgTitle').toggle();
});
```

Which works great for the first set of images but I need to hold the state for all future appends to the DOM, is this possible?

So, next 10 images are loaded and the DOM knows the current state e.g. class `.imgTitle` is hidden or not and all future clicks of the toggle button will affect all divs in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of toggling the individual images, you could add a class to `#images` and use CSS to hide all `.imgTitle`s inside of it when that class is present.

Then, you can simply call `.toggleClass()`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Wow! Really? Do you have a snippet of example code? This is new to me.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney: Not offhand.  Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: How can one class being present on a container determine whether a class inside it is visible or not. I think that's wat you're saying?

Comment: Using regular CSS selectors: `#images.TitlesHidden .imgTitle { display: none; }`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much! Thats a new way of class grouping to me. Judging by lack of answers, not only me. Works prefectly. Thanks once again.